# add part of the page section to the master layout in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt layout like below

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>
      <div class="bg-dark d-block">
        set content in page
      </div>

      <nuxt />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

but now I need to fill the section write `set content in page` to import from page component.

I mean I Like to import custom component in different pages to this section

Is it possible or is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use store data to do this

in your page :

```
this.$store.dispatch('changeLayoutComponent', 'componentName')
```

and in your nuxt layout use this data to show different components in different pages, you could use dynamic components to achive this

=> in your layout

```
<template>
    ...
    <component v-bind:is="currentTabComponent"></component>
    ...
</template>
<script>
  export default {
     data() {
       return {
          currentTabComponent: this.$store.state.componentName
       }
     },
     //watch store for changes
     watch: {
       "$store.state.componentName": function() {
            this.currentTabComponent= this.$store.state.componentName
       }
     }
  }
</script>
```